# Qual a diferença de isaccepted e hasaccepted?

Tags: suporte, busca

Nas pesquisas avançadas qual seria diferença de `isaccepted:yes` e `hasaccepted:yes` (ou `isaccepted:no` e `hasaccepted:no`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [`isaccepted:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes) retorna somente *"respostas"* que foram aceitas como corretas.
- [`isaccepted:no`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ano) retorna somente *"respostas"* que **não** foram
  aceitas como a correta da questão (independente se a questão tiver
  uma outra resposta escolhida)
- [`hasaccepted:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ayes) retorna *"perguntas"* que aceitaram uma resposta como correta.
- [`hasaccepted:no`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano) retorna *"perguntas"* que não aceitaram nenhuma resposta, pode retornar perguntas *com* ou *sem* respostas.

> Nota: Este último (`hasaccepted:no`) é muito bom para colaborar com novas respostas.

Comment: Essa pergunta e resposta são um dos melhores exemplos de um discreto 'tutorial' - muito bom. Podia ate ter uma TAG `tutorial` para ou algo similar referente à perguntas e respostas das funcionalidades auto explicativas para facilitar os novatos.