# Como aumentar a minha Reputação?

Tags: debate, reputação

Eu entrei na comunidade agora, sou aficionado com tecnologia. Queria saber como aumentar a reputação para poder fazer mais coisas nesta comunidade!

Grato.

Comment: Fazer boas perguntas e responder as perguntas que você sabe a resposta. Essas são as melhores formas de ganhar reputação. Mas, existem outras formas, como edições. Cada edição que você sugerir, e for aprovada, você ganha 2 pontos. Parece pouco, mas já é algo.

Comment: Lembrando, quando tiver um poco mais de reputação, poderá [falar em nosso chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e conversar conosco por lá. :p

Answer (score 26):

Aficionado com tecnologia ou tecnologia específica? Se for específica tem mais chances de ganhar pontos, eu mesmo respondo muitas perguntas de HTML, CSS, JavaScript e PHP que são mais da minha área, tem gente que responde muitas perguntas sobre C++ e C e assim vai.

Aqui no site, no **Help** já tem uma explicação de como ganhar pontos:

- [O que é reputação? Como faço para ganhar (*ou perder*) pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Segue um resumo:

Você pode ganhar no máximo 200 pontos de reputação por dia de qualquer combinação das atividades a seguir (Apenas as gratificações/recompensas recebidas e as respostas aceitas não estão sujeitas ao limite diário de reputação).

### Você ganha reputação quando:

- Uma pergunta sua recebe um voto a favor: +10 pontos.
- Uma resposta sua recebe um voto a favor: +10 pontos.
- Uma resposta sua é marcada como “aceita”: +15 pontos.
- Se você aceitar uma resposta de outra pessoa na sua pergunta: +2 pontos (se a resposta for sua própria não ganha pontos).
- Uma edição sugerida é aceita: +2 pontos (usuários com 2000 pontos ou mais não ganham pontos por edições).
- Sua resposta recebeu uma gratificação/recompensa: a gratificação é definida por quem esta oferecendo que pode ser de 50 até 500 pontos.
- Sua resposta recebeu uma gratificação/recompensa automaticamente: recebe metade da recompensa ([consulte mais detalhes sobre o funcionamento das gratificações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)).

### Como buscar perguntas sem resposta

Como eu expliquei em [Qual a diferença de isaccepted e hasaccepted?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2602/3635) você pode procurar perguntas que não tenham respostas aceitas usando o buscador digitando `hasaccepted:no` (neste caso tente fazer **uma resposta melhor** do que as existentes), clique para testar:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano

Você pode digitar no buscador pra procurar perguntas sem resposta digite isto na busca `answers:0`, clique aqui pra testar:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0

Se quiser buscar por uma tecnologia específica adicione algo como isto na busca `[NOME DA TAG QUE DESEJO]`, assim por exemplo:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D

Então pode combinar os termos na busca, por exemplo:

- Perguntas sobre HTML sem resposta:

  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+answers%3A0
- Perguntas sobre HTML e CSS sem resposta:

  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+%%5Bcss%5D+answers%3A0

Comment: São usuários com 2000 ao invés de 1000 que não ganham mais esses +2 pontos para sugestão de edição, quando se atinge 2000 pontos se tem um novo privilégio, as edições são aplicadas na hora sem a necessidade de ir para fila.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho então é um erro no Help, editei já, o texto de 1000 deve ser da época do Beta e não foi atualizado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento reporta como bug.

Comment: @JorgeB. vou reportar, é que estava querendo entender o transfix, e como não era um problema em algo que é usado todos os dias pensei em usa isto para "teste" ou estudar o transfix

Comment: @mgibsonbr Obrigado pela edição, baita gade minha =)

Comment: Me senti tentado a escrever uma seção sobre perda de reputação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa fiquei curioso, como seria isto, além do http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation? Seria por exemplo, 1. pedir para fazer seu trabalho, 2. postou foto de código, 3. Escreveu AJUDA no titulo? ... Obs: tem uma pergunta mais especifica sobre isto https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4489/3635

Comment: Não, seria algo do tipo "*recebeu voto negativo em pergunta ou resposta: -2 pontos*", "*deu um voto negativo em uma resposta: -1 ponto*", etc. Ou seja, exatamente como nos links que você deu.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, baseada na minha experiência com o SO em inglês e português, a estratégia (se podemos dizer assim) pode variar um pouco.

A resposta do Guilherme já explica como funciona a parte de pontuação do site, para saber por onde ir se deseja ganhar votos positivos. Então vou apenas complementar com algumas estratégias que pode adotar que impactam na pontuação.

## Concentre-se nas tecnologias que conhece

Você pode usar as *tags* para seguir as tecnologias que mais domina e ignorar as que não conhece.

Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, se você acredita que sabe bem apenas [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) e [hibernate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate), acompanhe apenas estas 2 tags e ignore todo o resto. Menos é mais aqui.

Assim, na página inicial, você pode focar apenas naquelas que te interessa. Você também pode criar filtros de pesquisa para mostrar as "melhores" perguntas para responder (não respondidas, com muitos votos positivos/visualizações e sem resposta, etc), como mostrado na [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5051/4492).

## Saiba se comunicar

Um bom português é essencial. Seja claro nas respostas, use bem a formatação, forneça as informações que o autor da pergunta precisa. Particularmente gosto de dar respostas mais curtas em geral, mas você pode encontrar seu próprio estilo.

## Marque território

Quando observar uma pergunta que acabou de ser criada e que consegue responder, forneça o quanto antes a resposta que o autor precisa. Depois, faça as edições necessárias para deixar um pouco melhor, adicionar outras informações, etc.

Normalmente, outros usuários desistem de responder a mesma pergunta quando ela já tem uma resposta que já atenda a dúvida. Se você se enrolar demais em fornecê-la, outro usuário irá fazê-lo antes de você.

## Se enturme

Está é mais para o Stack Overflow em português ou para comunidades com tamanho parecido.

Se deseja ficar próximo do pessoal mais ativo da comunidade, contribuindo aqui no [meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) e participando do [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com), inevitavelmente suas perguntas e questões terão a atenção deles, desde que atendam os critérios de qualidade do site, é claro.

Como são os usuários que mais acompanham todo o site, é provável que são os que mais distribuem votos positivos (e negativos). Carece de fonte confiável, mas dá para ter [uma noção](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote?MinRep=1000&MinUpvotes=600).

## Dedique tempo

Este eu considero **o mais importante de todos**. Não adianta atender à todo o resto dos itens anteriores se não tiver tempo para se dedicar ao site. E para pontuar bem precisa dedicar **muito** tempo. Quem passa mais tempo consegue ver primeiro as perguntas e respondê-las. Também tem mais tempo de fazer rápidas pesquisas para responder algumas perguntas que, inicialmente, não sabe responder com precisão.

Veja um exemplo do resultado em outra [rede](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) com um pouco de dedicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este pico foi de um período mais ativo, de menos de 2 horas por dia (somadas) que durou algumas semanas. Imagine agora os resultados, em termos de pontuação, caso fosse possível dedicar mais tempo? Isto é válido para qualquer usuário hábil em responder questões de algumas tecnologias.

Sem tempo, você vai precisar garimpar por perguntas não respondidas ou mal respondidas. Neste caso, procure por perguntas sem resposta, com apenas uma resposta ou respostas não aceitas ainda. Se tiver muitas visualizações, melhor ainda. A "vantagem" aqui é que você não precisa se preocupar com tempo e pode fornecer as respostas com calma.

Tente responder várias, mesmo que demore para receber os votos positivos (talvez nunca os receba). Você precisa fazer uma certa quantidade de respostas/perguntas no site para começar a "colher" os votos positivos ao longo do tempo.

## Editar perguntas/respostas antigas

Esta estratégia também funciona melhor no Stack Overflow em português ou para comunidades com tamanho parecido. Quando edita-se uma resposta/pergunta, a pergunta sobe para a página inicial, [ganhando destaque](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8241/4492) e aumentando a possibilidade de votos.