# O que fazer com respostas antigas negativadas?

Tags: debate

Hoje dando um "passeio" na minha conta, eu percebi que eu tinha 2 respostas antigas que foram negativas sem motivo (uma delas com motivo, mas eu tinha a corrigido muito tempo atrás).

- [Recursão para Inversão de Lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418264/157404)
- [Count dentro de um array com valores de outro array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406700/157404)

Estou querendo manter um histórico de respostas positivas, porém essas são boas respostas e eu gostaria de saber o que se deve fazer numa situação dessas. Deve-se pedir por uma reavaliação em algum lugar do site ou excluo as respostas ?

Comment: Essas respostas não são antigas, tem poucos meses de vida apenas. Nesses casos, alguém julgou que havia algum problema na qualidade dessas respostas. Isso é bom, classificar as respostas é o feedback que a comunidade tem para conseguir afastar as pérolas dos grãos de areia. A questão realmente é tentar descobrir o porquê de alguém ter as achado de baixa qualidade para, então, tomar um partido para entender se a crítica for cabível. Como pôde-se perceber, não li as respostas para tentar julgar algo sobre.

Comment: As vezes você perde um voto não por negativação. Sempre estão removendo contas fake e contas marionete as vezes você ganhou um upvote de uma dessas contas de uma olhada na guia [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/157404/jeanextreme002?tab=reputation) lá tem uma breve explicação do porque a alteração dos pontos de reputação.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>Quebrei seu galho lá :)</s>

Eu não me preocuparia com as respostas negativas depois que fez as devidas alterações. Elas não são, necessariamente, um sinal que sua resposta continua ruim (muitas vezes ela nunca foi ruim), pois há diversos fatores que podem manter sua resposta negativa mesmo depois de alterá-la:

- Quem votou negativo, antes de você melhorar/corrigir sua resposta, dificilmente vai passar ou muito menos lembrar da sua resposta novamente e retirar o voto negativo. Na verdade, isto é um dos problemas do Stack Overflow.
- Alguns usuários gostam de distribuir negativo sem motivo aparente e, depois disso, sua resposta não ficou em evidência o suficiente para receber um voto positivo de outro usuário para equilibrar isto.

Mesmo assim, você pode conseguir os votos positivos que deseja.

Quando você edita sua resposta, a pergunta vai subir para a página inicial e fica em evidência. Você pode fazer isto em horário comercial, que é o momento de mais movimento do site (presumo eu). As chances de ganhar votos positivos aumentam muito assim. Esta estratégia costuma funcionar tão bem aqui que algumas pessoas abusam, na minha opinião, disto. Mas particularmente não vejo nenhum problema em fazer isto de vez em quando e para corrigir algum erro, melhorar ou acrescentar mais algo.

Comment: Agora eu entendo o porque a galera faz edição em massa kkk. Muito bem explicado, obrigado.

Comment: Estou votando contra porque não concordei com o _quebra-galho_. No ambiente do SOpt, eu vejo o voto como uma forma democrática de expressar sua opinião sobre aquele conteúdo, e um voto por caridade não é algo que é bem enxergado na comunidade. Pelo menos, não para mim. Estratégias de conseguir voto positivo é mais por ganância do que preservação de qualidade e democracia.

Comment: @CypherPotato as respostas dele estão boas. Tanto que votei bem antes  (ontem) desta minha resposta. De certa forma, eu esperava que alguém não gostasse disto, mas foi uma brincadeira o "quebra-galho" :).

Comment: @CypherPotato, aliás, concordo com sua última frase.

Answer (score 8):

Independente das postagens serem novas ou antigas, as opções giram sempre em torno disso:

- Editar e melhorar (todos ganham)

OU

- Remover só se estiver completamente errada
  (mas sem excesso - remoção em massa também gera bloqueios, lembre-se que o conteúdo pertence à rede e não mais ao autor depois de postado)

OU

- Deixar como está se tem certeza que é uma ótima resposta

Se partir sempre do princípio que a votação está correta, vai se poupar de um monte de conjecturas desnecessárias, e toda melhoria é bem-vinda. E se por acaso (a probabilidade é baixa) dos votos estarem enganados, a melhoria é um ganho para todos da mesma forma, e naturalmente os positivos compensarão.

(até aqui, para ser neutro, escrevi sem visitar os links)

Sobre os links postados, não que isso vá mudar os votos (e nenhum foi meu), lembre-se que tem várias IDEs online que permitem você postar o código de maneira que o visitante veja que funciona. Aquela mais curtinha eu sequer entendi o que você tentou demonstrar, mas confesso que não analisei profundamente (por isso não votei nada ainda).

Complementando:

[Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/70)

Comment: Bacco, mas aí tem uma questão... no site não é legal por respostas por links justamente porque não há garantia que o conteúdo permanecerá o mesmo. É bacana ver um código pronto funcionando sem precisar copiar e executar no computador, mas não seria mais interessante deixar o código na resposta ao invés de em um IDE Online ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Ele quis dizer que o código **também** pode estar em um IDE online (com o respectivo link), mas como um complemento. O ideal é sempre ter o código na resposta.

Comment: as perguntas e respostas devem estar autocontidas no site, mas como disse o colega @hkotsubo, você pode complementar com uma demonstração no site externo. Seria algo a acrescentar ao post, sem retirar nada da resposta original.

Answer (score 8):

Sobre a resposta em [Recursão para Inversão de Lista em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418264/64969). Se você colocou ela aqui no Meta é sinal que pretende receber um feedback sobre ela, então vamos lá.

No momento em que escrevo, ela não apresenta votos negativos:

> [image: não há votos negativos na resposta]

Não consegui obter nenhuma informação através do [sumário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/418264/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) relativa a histórico de votos, apenas que em algum momento ela foi sinalizada como "baixa qualidade" porém negada pela revisão da sinalização.

Agora, que a resposta dá umas voltas grandes, ela dá. Você definiu uma função interna recursiva dentro da função de inversão, sendo que a função externa só tem  função de iniciar uma variável e determinar qual o primeiro ponto da recursão. Isso me lembra algo que estive lendo recentemente no [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237519) sobre o uso/ensino de recursões em lugares não apropriados, ou que seriam trivialmente tratáveis desenrolando o laço.

Vou incrementar sua resposta em dois passos:

1. tirando a recursão
2. tornando o laço incrementado
3. tirando a função interna

A parte de tirar a recursão, como se trata de uma recursão de cauda, é bem trivial. A recursão é feita decrementando-se o valor de `index`, o resto se mantém o mesmo. Logo, isso é possível substituir por um laço que começa com `index` recebendo o *primeiro valor* a ele passado e decrementando até chegar em 0 (fechado):

```
def inverter(lista):
    clone = []

    def adiciona(lista, index_inicial):
        for index in range(index_inicial, -1, -1): # porque o stop é aberto e preciso informar o decremento
            clone.append(lista[index])

    adiciona(lista,len(lista)-1)
    return clone
```

Agora, outra coisa que se pode perceber é: eu estou iterando no intervalo `(len(lista), 0]`. Então, existe uma possibilidade de eu fazer uma iteração de `[0, len(list))` que, matematicamente, fosse equivalente ao intervalo decrescente? Se existir uma bijeção entre os dois conjuntos, a resposta será sim. Inicialmente, vamos transformar em intervalos fechados? `[len(lista) - 1, 0]` e `[0, len(lista) - 1]`. Pronto. Agora eu preciso de uma função que mapeie os inteiro do seguinte jeito:

- `0 --> len(lista) - 1`
- `1 --> len(lista) - 2`
- `2 --> len(lista) - 3`
- ...
- `len(lista) - 3 --> 2`
- `len(lista) - 2 --> 1`
- `len(lista) - 1 --> 0`

Por acaso, essa função é `index_reverso(i) = len(lista) - 1 - i`. Portanto, se eu fizer a iteração de `[0, len(lista))` e, para todo índice dessa lista, aplicar `index_reverso`, eu obtenho a posição inversa da lista. Como essa é uma função simples, não preciso de fato escrevê-la, mas posso colocá-la diretamente no código:

```
def inverter(lista):
    clone = []

    def adiciona(lista, len_lista):
        for i in range(len_lista):
            clone.append(lista[len_lista - 1 - i])

    adiciona(lista,len(lista))
    return clone
```

Agora, como se pode perceber, a função `adiciona` se torna trivialmente substituível. Bastaria substitui-la diretamente onde ela é chamada:

```
def inverter(lista):
    clone = []

    len_lista = len(lista)
    for i in range(len_lista):
            clone.append(lista[len_lista - 1 - i])
    return clone
```

Outro ponto que não ajuda é que o nome da variável `clone` não indica o seu real significado. Ela não é um clone de ninguém. Talvez algo mais significativo fosse `lista_invertida`?

---

Sim, eu sei que variedade de respostas é algo positivo. Mas deve-se prezar sempre pela qualidade. Em compensação, havendo espaço para algo esotérico, [por que não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241694/64969)? Note que, nessa minha resposta satírica (pois já havia uma [resposta verdadeira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241669/64969) ou algo que se aproximasse disso) voltada apenas para entretenimento, eu deixo claro que estou fazendo coisas absurdas, motivado apenas pelo fato de que aquilo era um exercício.

> E, sim, minha resposta ganhou mais votos que a outra, que realmente tinha alguma pretensão de resposta